# How to delete the blank line in files

Tags: python

First i have an txt file i want to do two thing:

1. delete all the content which start with **#** except the first line then output the file
2. delete all the blank line the file

for step 1:

```
with open ("txt","r") as file1:
    temp=file1.read()
    c=re.sub(r"#\w+.*|#\s.*","",txt)
    print(c,file=open("temp","a"))
```

for step 2:

```
with open("temp","r+") as file2:
    txt=file2.read()
    c=re.sub(r"\n",' ',txt)
    print(c,file=open("txt","a"))
```

this is my txt :

```
#*&^%$
sunday
monday
#comment
rainy
#weather
#1998
cloudy
```

the step is correct but the step is uncorrect how can i modify it? and if i want to delete only line 2 ~line 6 how can i do it????

Comment: An empty line is characterized by two newlines consecutively. A # at beginning of first line is characterized by the fact that not any character is before it.

Comment: `c=re.sub(r"\n",' ',txt)` -> `c=re.sub(r"\n\n",'\n',txt)` (or use `r"\n\s*\n` if "empty line" may mean lines with only spaces etc), because `\n` means newline character, not an empty line.

Comment: @h4z3 really  useful!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do

```
def uncomment(filepath):
  with open(filepath, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:] # read all the lines except the first
    lines = [line.split("#")[0].rstrip() for line in lines]
    filtered_lines = [line for line in lines if line != '']
    return filtered_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeps the first line unchanged

**Code**

```
with open ("txt.txt","r") as ifile, open('result.txt', 'w') as ofile:
  for i, line in enumerate(ifile):
    if i == 0:
      ofile.write(line)  # keeps first line
    else:
      new_line = line.rstrip().split('#')[0] # ignore blank line and remove comments
      if new_line: 
        ofile.write(new_line + '\n')
```

**Test**

Input File: *txt.txt*

```
#*&^%$
sunday  # good day
monday

#comment
rainy # tomorrow
#weather



#1998
cloudy
```

Output file (keeps first line): *results.txt*

```
#*&^%$
sunday  
monday
rainy 
cloudy
```